# Implementing Builder interface in Effective Java book

Tags: java

I am reading Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. At the top of page 16, he says:

```
Note that our NutritionFacts.Builder class could be declared to implement
Builder<NutritionFacts>.
```

But how can a "Builder" implement a "Builder" interface because there is a namespace collision there, e.g.:

```
public static class Builder implements Builder<NutritionFacts>...
```

Should I rename the inner static class to something like NutritionFacts.NutritionBuilder or what?

Here is the builder pattern he provided:

```
// Builder Pattern
public class NutritionFacts {
 private final int servingSize;
 private final int servings;
 private final int calories;
 private final int fat;
 private final int sodium;
 private final int carbohydrate;

public static class Builder {
    // Required parameters
    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;

    // Optional parameters - initialized to default values
    private int calories      = 0;
    private int fat           = 0;
    private int carbohydrate  = 0;
    private int sodium        = 0;

    public Builder(int servingSize, int servings) {
        this.servingSize = servingSize;
        this.servings    = servings;
    }

    public Builder calories(int val)
        { calories = val;      return this; }
    public Builder fat(int val)
        { fat = val;           return this; }
    public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
        { carbohydrate = val;  return this; }
    public Builder sodium(int val)
        { sodium = val;        return this; }

    public NutritionFacts build() {
        return new NutritionFacts(this);
    }
}

private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
    servingSize  = builder.servingSize;
    servings     = builder.servings;
    calories     = builder.calories;
    fat          = builder.fat;
    sodium       = builder.sodium;
    carbohydrate = builder.carbohydrate;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could fully qualify the interface name.

i.e:

```
public static class Builder implements my.package.Builder<NutritionFacts> {
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that - but I am not sure if that is what the author meant. Maybe he meant moving the builder class somewhere else? Doesn't seem likely though...

Comment: I don't think moving the builder class would help, wherever it is its name still conflicts with the interface. Basically your options are to change the name of the class, change the name of the interface or fully qualify the interface in the class declaration. In my mind, qualifying the interface seems the change with the least impact